# ObjectiveC - Read from console string with multiple lines (Breaks\newLine)

Tags: objective-c, string, console-application, newline, scanf

Is there a way in objectiveC to read a string with multiple lines from user input in the console?
I'm making a simple console app in Xcode, which i want people to be able to paste SQL queries which may be in few lines.

Currently i'm using:

```
char strIn[512];
NSMutableString* str;
scanf("%[^\n]", strIn);
str = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:strIn];
NSLog(@"\n%@",str);
```

But this only gets the first line.
Remember - this is not about reading from file, but only from the console.
thanks.

Comment: How many lines do you want to input? Or do you want to input until `EOF`? Or how would you determine when to stop?

Comment: hi, the user is suppose to paste an SQL query in the console, not in a file, something like
select names 
from students, sheets 
where a=b

Comment: So maybe scan until the closing ";"?

Comment: Ye, but how can i get the whole expression, if it is more than 1 line?

Comment: @user2216210 Use `fread()` or `fgets()`.

Comment: @H2CO3 thanks but im not using a file, can you give an example according to the code i provided in my post?

Comment: @user2216210 You know the standard input is a file too? You know there's a global variable called `stdin`?

Comment: @H2CO3 - Yes i know realize that console is like a file to this matter.

Comment: @user2216210 Cool, then you can use those functions now, right?

Comment: H2CO3 and Martin - Yes i now realize that console is like a file to this matter. Thank you very much for the help, but i cant find a way to stop bytes import when the lines are finished. i have to press Enter again and only than the program continues. Can anyone please provide an example of getting few lines from the console to a string? I cant find the way, sorry for bothering. (The semi-colon works good but its not what i need and i cant manipulate it to my needs).

Comment: @user2216210: The console usually buffers lines before they are sent to the program, therefore you will always have to read complete lines. There is no easy way around that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code should help you to get started. It reads from standard input and collects the input lines in the `inputString` variable, until a semi-colon is found.

```
NSFileHandle *inputFile = [NSFileHandle fileHandleWithStandardInput];
NSMutableString *inputString = [NSMutableString string];

do {
    // Read from stdin, check for EOF:
    NSData *data = [inputFile availableData];
    if ([data length] == 0) {
        NSLog(@"EOF");
        break;
    }
    // Convert to NSString, replace newlines by spaces, append to current input:
    NSMutableString *tmp = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [tmp replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@" " options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [tmp length])];
    [inputString appendString:tmp];
    // Check for semi-colon:
} while ([inputString rangeOfString:@";"].location == NSNotFound);

NSLog(@"input=%@", inputString);
```

(Note that this sample code simple checks for a semi-colon somewhere in the input. It does not check if the semi-colon is e.g. embedded in a string.)